# SymbolRenderingModeをSwiftUIのForEachで選択させたいが実行時エラー(Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS)になってしまう。

Tags: swift, swiftui

SwiftUIのImageでSF Symbolsを表示させる際のオプションとして`.symbolRenderingMode(SymbolRenderingMode)`が用意されていますが、これをUI側で選択できるようにPickerとForEachで全てのオプションを表示できるようにしたいのですが、以下のように実装したのですが、実行時にエラーとなってしまいます。

### エラー内容

`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16d89fff0)`

### 謎

`SymbolRenderingMode`と同じようなものとして`SymbolVariants`があるのですが、こちらは同じような実装をしても問題なく実行が可能でした。

違いは`SymbolVariants`はデフォルトでHashableに準拠していることぐらいです。

### ソースコード

```swift
import SwiftUI

extension SymbolRenderingMode: CaseIterable, Identifiable, RawRepresentable, Hashable {
  public var id: String {
    return self.rawValue
  }
  
  public init?(rawValue: String) {
    switch rawValue {
      case "palette": self = .palette
      case "multicolor": self = .multicolor
      case "hierarchical": self = .hierarchical
      case "monochrome": self = .monochrome
      default:
        return nil
    }
  }

  public var rawValue: String {
    switch self {
      case .palette: return "palette"
      case .multicolor: return "multicolor"
      case .hierarchical: return "hierarchical"
      case .monochrome: return "monochrome"
      default: fatalError()
    }
  }

  public static var allCases: [SymbolRenderingMode] {
    return [.monochrome, .hierarchical, .multicolor, .palette]
  }
}

struct TestView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ForEach(SymbolRenderingMode.allCases) { mode in
      Text(mode.rawValue)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SymbolRenderingModeをバインド？する新しい列挙型を用意すればエラーなく動作しますが、元のコードが動作しない理由を知りたいです。

```swift
enum BindSymbolRenderingMode: String, CaseIterable, Hashable, Identifiable {
  case palette
  case multicolor
  case hierarchical
  case monochrome

  var id: String {
    return self.rawValue
  }

  var bind: SymbolRenderingMode {
    switch self {
      case .palette: return .palette
      case .multicolor: return .multicolor
      case .hierarchical: return .hierarchical
      case .monochrome: return .monochrome
    }
  }
}
```